# how to get all timezone names in ICU

Tags: c++, datetime, boost, icu

I am using boost::locale with ICU Backend to do time conversion between different timezones.when creating boost::local::Calendar, I can pass in a string like "America/New_York" to specify the timezone information.

but how do I get a list of all valid timezone names?

from ICU doc, it mentioned that users can use TimeZone.getAvailableIDs() method to iterate through all timezone names. but I can't even find a method called getAvailableIDs in timezone.h.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `TimeZone.createEnumeration()` to get a list of all timezone names. it does says in the doc that using `getAvailabeIDs`, but this method seems not exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to implement it like this, using ICU 4.4.2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unicode/timezone.h>
#include <unicode/unistr.h>

using namespace icu;

int main()
{
   StringEnumeration *timeZoneIds = TimeZone::createEnumeration();

   UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
   const UnicodeString *zoneId = timeZoneIds->snext(status);

   while (zoneId != NULL && status == U_ZERO_ERROR)
   {
      std::string zoneIdString;
      zoneId->toUTF8String(zoneIdString);

      std::cout << zoneIdString << std::endl;

      zoneId = timeZoneIds->snext(status);
   }

   delete timeZoneIds;

   return 0;
}
```